# コードを実行すると btn_click が定義されていないというエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3

Python3で以下のコードを入力すると "`btn_click` が定義されていない" というエラーが出ます。`btn2_click` も同様に定義されません。

どこを変えればエラーなく動作するようになるでしょうか。

```
import tkinter
# 画面作成
tki = tkinter.Tk()
tki.geometry('400x200') # 画面サイズの設定
tki.title('がちゃ') # 画面タイトルの設定

# ボタンの作成
btn  = tkinter.Button(tki, text='単発',height=2,width=20,command=btn_click) # ボタンの設定
btn.place(x=30, y=100) #ボタン位置
btn2 = tkinter.Button(tki, text='10',height=2,width=20,command=btn2_click) # ボタンの設定
btn2.place(x=230, y=100) #ボタン位置
  
def btn_click():
    import tkinter
    tki2=tkinter.Tk()
    tki2.geometry('400x200')
    tki2.title('1')
    btn3  = tkinter.Button(tki2, text='yes',height=2,width=20) # ボタンの設定
    btn4  = tkinter.Button(tki2, text='no',height=2,width=20)
    btn3.place(x=30,y=100)
    btn4.place(x=230,y=100)

def btn2_click():
    import tkinter
    tki3=tkinter.Tk()
    tki3.geometry('400x200')
    tki3.title('10')
    btn5  = tkinter.Button(tki2, text='yes',height=2,width=20) # ボタンの設定
    btn6  = tkinter.Button(tki2, text='no',height=2,width=20)
    btn5.place(x=30,y=100)
    btn6.place(x=230,y=100)

# 画面をそのまま表示
tki.mainloop()
```

Comment: エラーメッセージも略さずに全てを提示してみてください。あとPC・OS・IDE等の動作環境やPythonの版数の情報もあると良いでしょう。ちなみに単純に記述位置(順番)の問題では？ 2つの`def btn...`を記述した後に`btn = tkinter.Button(...)`以後の行を移動してみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

Pythonに限らず, 変数を使用する前に参照するとたいていエラーです (特に動的型付け言語では)
すぐそこに定義してる, としても実行時に後方参照してたらダメ

```py
result = hed + v * 3   #  未定義変数を扱ってるのでエラー

hed = 1
v = 2
print(result)
```

また, 変数ではなく関数であっても同様。関数を定義する前に参照してはいけない
質問の `btn_click` は, 「ボタンの作成」実行時点では未定義です

```py
result = fn   #  関数 fn を定義前に扱うとエラー
```

---

ただし, 以下の場合は少し事情が異なります

- 関数 `fn` を**定義**する段階では `hed`,`v` はエラーではない
- 関数 `fn` **実行**時(呼び出し時) では, `hed`,`v` を参照しようとするので, その時点で未定義だとエラー

この場合の順序は, `fn`の定義 --> `hed`,`v` の定義 --> その後 `fn()` を呼び出しているのでエラーは発生しない

※ 本来は, `hed`,`v` は引数で与えるべきだが参照の説明のための この構造

```py
def fn():
    result = hed + v * 3
    return result

hed = 'あ'
v = 'は'
print(fn())
hed = 'え'
v = 'へ'
print(fn())
```

Answer (score 0):

コメント指摘の通り、`btn_click`を定義するよりも前の行で`btn_click`を呼び出すと、下記のように[`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError)が発生します。

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'btn_click' is not defined
```

ちなみに`btn5  = tkinter.Button(tki2, text='yes',height=2,width=20)`でも`NameError`が発生します。
これは`btn2_click`関数のスコープ内で`tki2`が定義されていないことが原因です。
`tki3`の打ち間違いでないかご確認ください。

サンプルコードのように書き直すことで正常動作を確認しました。

**サンプルコード**

```
import tkinter
# 画面作成
tki = tkinter.Tk()
tki.geometry('400x200') # 画面サイズの設定
tki.title('がちゃ') # 画面タイトルの設定

def btn_click():
    import tkinter
    tki2=tkinter.Tk()
    tki2.geometry('400x200')
    tki2.title('1')
    btn3  = tkinter.Button(tki2, text='yes',height=2,width=20) # ボタンの設定
    btn4  = tkinter.Button(tki2, text='no',height=2,width=20)
    btn3.place(x=30,y=100)
    btn4.place(x=230,y=100)

def btn2_click():
    import tkinter
    tki3=tkinter.Tk()
    tki3.geometry('400x200')
    tki3.title('10')
    btn5  = tkinter.Button(tki3, text='yes',height=2,width=20) # ボタンの設定
    btn6  = tkinter.Button(tki3, text='no',height=2,width=20)
    btn5.place(x=30,y=100)
    btn6.place(x=230,y=100)

# ボタンの作成
btn  = tkinter.Button(tki, text='単発',height=2,width=20,command=btn_click) # ボタンの設定
btn.place(x=30, y=100) #ボタン位置
btn2 = tkinter.Button(tki, text='10',height=2,width=20,command=btn2_click) # ボタンの設定
btn2.place(x=230, y=100) #ボタン位置

# 画面をそのまま表示
tki.mainloop()
```